# How to control drag button to view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button

I ma having some issues when trying to link a button to a view controller using swift / xcode.

The tutorial i am following tells me to control click and drag to the view controller (which looks as follows)

```
//
//  ButtonViewController.swift
//  Relocate
//
//  Created by on 28/07/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 com.ricki.relocate. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ButtonViewController : UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Apparently some options should appear for me to make an outlet but, the editor isn't letting me place it in the view controller file.

Is there a pre-requisite task i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the set the class of the view controller to your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, look at the `Identity Inspector` tab for the button view controller. Make sure it says `ButtonViewController` in the `Class` field.